# Трикотажная ткань?

Tags: употребление-слов

Как вы относитесь к словосочетанию "трикотажная ткань"? Мне слышится противоречие: ткань оттого и ткань, что ее ткут. Либо трикотажная, либо ткань. Но ведь употребляется. Помогите разобраться, допустимо ли или лучше избегать данного словосочетания?

Answer (score 3):

Понятие "ткань" весьма широкое, было бы ошибкой рассматривать исключительно прямое значение слова "ткать - ткань" и считать, что это только накрест переплетенные нити.

Если уж существуют ткани различных органов и даже ткань художественного произведения, то трикотажная ткань тем более имеет право на существование. Ткань - это материал, а трикотажная ткань - это трикотажный материал.

Употребление этого термина позволяет различать трикотаж как ткань и трикотаж как изделие.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

Употребление выражения "трикотажные ткани" зависит от стиля, как общеупотребительное выражение оно применяется часто.

В то же время существует определенная терминология - это уже специальная лексика. Раньше в Гостах разделяли, к примеру, "ТКАНИ чистошерстяные, шерстяные, шелковые  и трикотажные ПОЛОТНА".

Сейчас описание может строиться путем указания на состав ткани и на тип плетения. Например: Спортивный Трикотаж "Прима". ПРИМА (ИНТЕРЛОК) Состав - 100 % полиэфирная ткань. Тип плетения - трикотажное. Стандартная ширина ткани на складе 160 см. Эту ткань часто можно встретить в обычной жизни, в основном из хлопка.

Answer (score 3):

София, дело в том, что само слово "трикотаж" заимствовано из французкого, где оно имеет значение " трикотажная ткань". Мне кажется, "трикотажная ткань" - это плеоназм. Хотя, может, вы и правы.

Comment: Да, но в русских толковых словарях указывается два значения слова "трикотаж": машинная вязаная ткань и изделия из такой ткани. А о французском происхождении слова мало кто подозревает, и разумеется, оно не учитывается при составлении словосочетаний.

Answer (score 2):

Я тоже считаю, что это некорректно, просто перепутали термины.

Следует отличать ткани от текстильных полотен, выработанных другими способами: трикотажных полотен, вырабатываемых путём вязания, то есть образования взаимосвязанных петельных рядов, нетканых материалов (к которым можно относить также валяльно-войлочные и холстопрошивные материалы).

На грамотных сайтах различают термины ткань и трикотажное волокно.